# How to write line by line request output

Tags: python

I am trying to write line by line the JSON output from my Python request.  I already checked some similar issue on StackOverflow in the question: [write to file line by line python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130987/write-to-file-line-by-line-python), without success.

Here is the code:

```py
myfile = open ("data.txt", "a")

    for item in pretty_json["geonames"]:

        print (item["geonameId"],item["name"])

        myfile.write ("%s\n" % item["geonameId"] + "https://www.geonames.org/" + item["name"])

    myfile.close()
```

Here the output from my pretty_json["geonames"]

```
{
  "adminCode1": "FR",
  "lng": "7.2612",
  "geonameId": 2661847,
  "toponymName": "Aeschlenberg",
  "countryId": "2658434",
  "fcl": "P",
  "population": 0,
  "countryCode": "CH",
  "name": "Aeschlenberg",
  "fclName": "city, village,...",
  "adminCodes1": {
    "ISO3166_2": "FR"
  },
  "countryName": "Switzerland",
  "fcodeName": "populated place",
  "adminName1": "Fribourg",
  "lat": "46.78663",
  "fcode": "PPL"
}
```

Then, as output saved on my data.txt, I'm having :

```
11048419
https://www.geonames.org/Aïre2661847
https://www.geonames.org/Aeschlenberg2661880
https://www.geonames.org/Aarberg6295535
```

The expected result should be something like:

```
Aïre , https://www.geonames.org/11048419
Aeschlenberg , https://www.geonames.org/2661847
Aarberg , https://www.geonames.org/2661880
```

Writing the output in CSV could be a solution?

Regards.

Comment: Could you provide us with some data from data.txt? Are they the same as your expected outputs?

Comment: please provide a sample `pretty_json["geonames"]` to make this easier. look at how to make a [mcve]

Comment: Hi. What I'm having in my data.txt (as output from my http request) is the first output I posted just after the code

Comment: @Pelide, once again, post the contents of `pretty_json["geonames"]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just added on my post the JSON output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open("data.txt", "a") as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)                #Create Writer Object
    for item in pretty_json["geonames"]:       #Iterate list
        writer.writerow([item["name"], "https://www.geonames.org/{}".format(item["geonameId"])])  #Write row.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the same screen output to your file. That's easy. If you are on python 3 just add to your print function:

```
print (item["geonameId"],item["name"], file=myfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compose a proper printing format for the needed items:

```
...
for item in pretty_json["geonames"]:
    print("{}, https://www.geonames.org/{}".format(item["name"], item["geonameId"]))
```

Sample output:

```
Aeschlenberg, https://www.geonames.org/2661847
```